# MVVM Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

My problem is this : I have a Student class like this :

```
private int _id

private string _name;

private int _age;

private ICollection<Grade> _grades;
```

My Grade class is this :

```
private int _id

private string _gradeval;

private Student _student;
```

I have a StudentVM file like this, I don't have a VM for grade :

```
private string _nameui;

private int _ageui;
```

I have the following xaml file :

```
<Window x:Class="CodeFirstMVVM.App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CodeFirstMVVM.App.ViewModels"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=StudentView}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="900">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Left="131" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Canvas.Top="51" Width="283" Name="txtName" Text="{Binding NameUI}"/>
            <TextBox Height="23" Canvas.Left="131" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Canvas.Top="86" Width="283" Name="txtAge" Text="{Binding AgeUI}"/>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dg01" ItemsSource="{Binding Entities, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}" CanUserAddRows="False" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="201" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="200" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age" Width="50" />

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName =dg01, Path=SelectedItem.Grades, Mode=TwoWay}"  Canvas.Left="622" Canvas.Top="201" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding GradeValue}" Header="Grades"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see there are two datagrids. First one shows Student information and the second is supposed to show grades of the selected student in first datagrid. I can easily see student info in text boxes, but I can't see the grades of selected student. When I add new grades I can see the grades. But when I close and open the window, I can't see previously entered grades. But I can see them in the database. I think I'm doing something wrong about binding grades but I don't know what. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the ViewModel and Model for both..

Comment: Can you see if the `Output` window of Visual Studio gives you any errors at runtime? It'll give us something more to work with.

Comment: @aevitas there are no errors.

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly populating the model with Grade items? If you break execution, does `SelectedEntity.Grades` have any elements?

Comment: *How can I check it? I'm kind of new to this*... you can read tutorials to actually learn the language before trying to use it. I'm assuming that you wouldn't try to drive a car before learning how to, so what's different with programming?

Comment: *I can show other codes if necessary, I'm not pasting all of it because there is too much code to paste*... no one asked you to show all of it. You need to show [just enough to demonstrate your problem and no more](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your current code does *not* demonstrate your problem, so it's pretty unlikely that anyone can *guess* what you did wrong. Please edit your question to show the *relevant* code *and no more*.

Comment: I have imporved the question.